# When are things actually rendered and available in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, render

So I am pulling in a template in the render() method in BackBone.

```
var html = $(template).render();
this.el.html(html);
```

I have some css defined for that template, for instance a percent width on an element. I can't seem to get that height using jquery after the lines above. So does that actually render that to DOM, when do elements get calculated?

Thx
Ralph

Comment: I think you need `this.$el.html(html)` (with the `$`).  But yes, that's just the JQuery `html` method, so it should render immediately.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to use the jquery cached element `this.$el.html(html)`.
After this the view it's already rendered, but not attached to the DOM, hence, properties like height or width will be undefined (or zero).

For example, this should return something:

```
var html = $(template).render();
this.$el.html(html);
this.$el.appendTo("body");
console.log(this.$el.height());
```

Comment: Well I did figure out something. I changed my CSS to have a height of 50px for some element that I tested right after $el.html(html). It came back correctly, but the 50% didn't. So when and how do percentages get calculated.

Comment: Percentage properties like width and height are calculated based on the parent element, so, if the view it's not attached to the DOM, it has no parent at all.